# C# delegate with generic return Typ of List

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I need to define a delegate with a generic List return type, whats the best way of doing this?

```
delegate List<T> TestDelegate(string arg1, string arg2);
```

Then I want to do this

```
TestDelegate td = new TestDelegate(Method1);
```

or this

```
TestDelegate td = new TestDelegate(Method2);
```

Signature of Method1 and Method2:

```
List<MyClass1> Method1(string arg1, string arg2)
List<MyClass2> Method2(string arg1, string arg2)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the delegate itself generic:

```
delegate List<T> TestDelegate<T>(string arg1, string arg2);

var td1 = new TestDelegate<MyClass1>(Method1);
var td2 = new TestDelegate<MyClass2>(Method2);
```

Note the additional `<T>` in the delegate declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can define abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyClass{ 
    public String GenericProperty{get;set;}
}
```

and you specific class:

```
public MyClass1 : MyClass {
    public String SpecificProperty{get; set;}
}
public MyClass2 : MyClass {
    public String OtherSpecificProperty{get; set;}
}
```

Then the delegate becomes:

```
delegate List<MyClass> TestDelegate(string arg1, string arg2);
List<MyClass> Method1(string arg1, string arg2)
List<MyClass> Method2(string arg1, string arg2)

List<MyClass> = new TestDelegate(Method1);
List<MyClass> = new TestDelegate(Method2);
```

Comment: Won't work, since `List<MyClass>` is not a supertype of `List<MyClass1>` (try it, you'll get a compile error). `List<T>` is not covariant: Imagine what would happen if you tried `returnValue.Add(new MyClass2())` on the value returned by `Method1`.